# Why is the intercept typed in as a 1 in stats packages (R, python)

Tags: regression, software, intercept

When using statistics software, When defining your linear models, why is the intercept typed in as a 1, rather than "const" or "intercept" or something. What significance does 1 have?

Is there some historic reason? Or is this logical in some way I am failing to grasp? The intercept could very well be any number.

Example from statsmodels library in python:

```
model = smf.ols('Height ~ 1', data = height_sample_data)
```

I know lmer package for R is very similar.

Comment: The intercept is the *coefficient* (which indeed could have any value), but what you enter into the regression program when you fit the model are not the coefficients, but the things you multiply the coefficients by in the regression equation (the $x$'s). What do you multiply the intercept by in the regression equation?  (Note that $\beta_0 \times 1 = \beta_0$.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is logical, once you consider the matrix notation that your formula will be translated into internally. In the matrix, the non-constant predictors will be translated into (one or more) columns, and the intercept will be translated into a column consisting entirely of ones.

For instance, in R you would write [a very simple OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) as:

```
lm(z~1+x+y)
```

In matrix notation, this would be translated into a model

$$ \begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \\ \vdots \\ z_n \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 1 & x_2 & y_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n & y_n \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \beta_x \\ \beta_z \end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_1 \\ \epsilon_2 \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon_n \end{pmatrix},
$$

and now you see where the $1$ comes from.

---

Actually, you could leave the `1+` out, since R will always presume you want to include an intercept, so this is completely equivalent to

```
lm(z~x+y).
```

However, if you want to *suppress* the intercept, you would write something like

```
lm(z~x+y-1),
```

which would be translated into a matrix *without* a 1 column:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \\ \vdots \\ z_n \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots  \\ x_n & y_n \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \beta_x \\ \beta_z \end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_1 \\ \epsilon_2 \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon_n \end{pmatrix},
$$